# What's written on the wall?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

On both Earth 1 and Earth 2, the Time Vault has what appears to be braille text all over the its walls.

[image: Time Vault Text]

### What, if anything, does the braille say? Does it read the same between universes?

Comment: "Be sure to drink your Ovaltine."

Comment: I'm going to unshamefuly promote [my very own "Braille to text" tool](http://mgarciaisaia.github.io/braille-facil/) so you can easily try to find out which text corresponds to a given Braille pattern.

Comment: From Movies.se [Are the raised dot plastic wall tiles really Braille?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/are-the-raised-dot-plastic-wall-tiles-really-braille)

Answer (score 36):

Not only does it not say anything intelligible in braille, but it would appear that Reverse-Flash decorated his super-secret "vault" with $3 room tiles from [allmodern](https://www.allmodern.com/Inhabit-Wall-Flats-Braille-Panel-Wallpaper-BRAWF-INH1175.html) and spray painted them silver to make them look futuristic.

What a poser.

[image]

<sub><sup>h/t to reddit user [Elayne7](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlashTV/comments/2rhp8w/can_somebody_who_knows_braille_translate_what_is/con5lbj)</sup></sub>

Comment: @pointlessspike - Cheers. Edited accordingly.

Comment: For the record, this tile reads: `ed z er` / `of ed the`.  Assuming it's not upside down, in which case it's `n z er` / `of ed z`.  This is based on [English Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille), but it's entirely possible it might be some other language.  Unlikely though.

Comment: In French Braille, it's `ëzï àëè`, or `nzï àëz` if it's upside-down.

Comment: And now your answer is a partial - which is what I was trying to avoid by asking separate, but related questions. Now you don't get an accept.

Comment: @phantom42 - Partial? Surely mentioning that it's probably decorative covers the second point?

Comment: They move/transform in-universe, so no, it does not cover the second point.

Comment: You mean like I originally  had it before Richard combined them?

Comment: And actually, you're right. It's not a partial answer, now it's just wrong, as the fact that panels transform means that they are not just $3 panels from some store.

Comment: @phantom42 Why don't you edit your question to point out the fact that they move/transform? That seems like key information to me that is lacking in your question since moving/transforming means it is either random coolness or trying to communicate something which seems to be the heart of your question...

Comment: Thought about translating the ones on the walls, but it would probably be a waste of time - many of them are sideways, so it'd be toss-up which reading to give, but each of them appears to be one of two variants - the 5-dot pattern seen on the upper left and lower right of this tile, and the 4-dot pattern in the other 4 positions, flipped in various orientations.  Very few such patterns translate to common letters - most of those only have 2-3 dots.  I highly doubt there's any hidden message here, it's most likely just done because it looks cool.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I concur. These tiles are gibberish. When you put lots of them together in different orders, they still spell gibberish

Comment: Maybe the message is spelled out temporally instead of spatially... (pure speculation).

Answer (score 2):

As a person who knows Braille, I can confidently say that this isn't Braille. True, it is braille formatting, but Darrel Hoffman is right as to what it says. Odds are the producers just flipped through a braille book and picked their favorite looking symbols.

Comment: But the symbols move and transform, this would change the meaning.

Comment: As I pointed out above, this isn't braille period. These are decorative tiles that mean nothing at all.

Answer (score -3):

Zoom is the Reverse-Flash, the alter ego. Perhaps, the braille that is being communicated is not the braille that appears on Wells' Lair wall but the reverse one; the braille that doesn't.

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F.  Perhaps you could explain what you mean?  Presumably if there is 1 thing it says there are a *very large* number of things it does not.  Besides, that's not the question; the question is, assuming that it *is* Braille, what does it say?

Comment: Do you mean to read the blanks as dots and vice versa and interpret that as Braille?  The whitespace in Braille doesn't necessarily form characters; there are only 38 basic characters out of 63 possible sets; the inverses of "r", "s" and "t", for instance, don't make characters.