# What is the purpose of the designs on the wall?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

On both Earth 1 and Earth 2, there is what appears to be braille writing on the walls of the Time Vault. It seems to have no functional purpose.

[image: time vault writing]

### Why is there braille writing, or whatever the design is all over the walls?

To my knowledge, this has not been addressed at all in the show, but I have no idea if this is something from the comics.

Even if the designs are *not* braille, why are they there?

Comment: I suspect the answer to this will be the same as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/whats-written-on-the-wall

Comment: @PointlessSpike - It is indeed a dupe. The "braille" doesn't say anything which means that it's purely decorational.

Comment: Well, no. Even if it doesn't *say* something, it could still have a purpose.

Comment: @Richard Out of universe, they got some cheap and meaningless tiles from allmodern to use on the film set. In-universe, might there not still be some significance to them?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Even if that is the case, we certainly don't need two semi-identical questions to explore it.

Comment: They are two separate, but related questions. Richard answered the other one regarding what it does/doesn't say, but did not address the function/purpose, which would make it a partial answer if combined. The fact that it doesn't say anything does not mean there is no purpose.

Comment: @phantom42 - I've widened the dupe slightly to encompass the in-universe significance.

Comment: Editing the other question to *make* it a dupe seems really shady to me. But, whatever.

Comment: @phantom42 - Given that this was already on the verge of being closed as a dupe when I made the edit (and has now been closed as a dupe), I really don't see that it makes any difference. Feel free to revert one or both to their original formats. Since I won't be changing my VTC, it makes very little difference to me.

Comment: This does not feel like a dupe at all.